# How to check all sites a user has owner permission on in SharePoint Office 365

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, office365

I want to delete an admin user account and for that I want to check all sites where that user has owner permissions, because I want to make sure that there isn't a site where that user is the only owner, since it might cause trouble later after deleting the user.
I tried looking for a way to view all sites a user own but couldn't find any, and right now I'm a bit stuck.
Anyone knows maybe how to do that?

Comment: Which "owner" permission? Member of Classic UI sites Owner SharePoint group? Or the Modern UI Owner AD group? Or Site Collection Administrator?

Comment: Whichever that is for example: https://imgur.com/a/PTTlGVI